# Getting permission issue in Automation account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-runbook, runbook

I am trying to get list of expiring App registrations in 7 days. In local it is working perfectly but I facing Insufficient privileges issue in automation account. I am the global administrator of the account and provided permission to service connection api below are the permissions
[image]

I literally given all the permission but don't know what i am missing. Below is the error

```
Get-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing GetApplications Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. RequestId: a83caa17-1c58-433a-b0ea-f4a3f8a43d7f DateTimeStamp: Mon, 14 Feb 2022 04:56:58 GMT HttpStatusCode: Forbidden HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden HttpResponseStatus: Completed At line:11 char:17 + $Applications = Get-AzureADApplication -all $true + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADApplication], ApiException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetApplication
```

And below is the script

```
#Connect-AzureAD
$Applications = Get-AzureADApplication -all $true
$Logs = @()

$Days = 7


$AlreadyExpired = "YES"

$now = get-date

foreach ($app in $Applications) {
    $AppName = $app.DisplayName
    $AppID = $app.objectid
    $ApplID = $app.AppId
    $AppCreds = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $AppID | select PasswordCredentials, KeyCredentials
    $secret = $AppCreds.PasswordCredentials
    $cert = $AppCreds.KeyCredentials

    foreach ($s in $secret) {
        $StartDate = $s.StartDate
        $EndDate = $s.EndDate
        $operation = $EndDate - $now
        $ODays = $operation.Days

        if ($AlreadyExpired -eq "No") {
            if ($ODays -le $Days -and $ODays -ge 0) {

                $Owner = Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $app.ObjectId
                $Username = $Owner.UserPrincipalName -join ";"
                $OwnerID = $Owner.ObjectID -join ";"
                if ($owner.UserPrincipalName -eq $Null) {
                    $Username = $Owner.DisplayName + " **<This is an Application>**"
                }
                if ($Owner.DisplayName -eq $null) {
                    $Username = "<<No Owner>>"
                }

                $Log = New-Object System.Object

                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ApplicationName" -Value $AppName
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ApplicationID" -Value $ApplID
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Secret Start Date" -Value $StartDate
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Secret End Date" -value $EndDate
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Certificate Start Date" -Value $Null
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Certificate End Date" -value $Null
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Owner" -Value $Username
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Owner_ObjectID" -value $OwnerID

                $Logs += $Log
            }
        }
        elseif ($AlreadyExpired -eq "Yes") {
            if ($ODays -le $Days) {
                $Owner = Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $app.ObjectId
                $Username = $Owner.UserPrincipalName -join ";"
                $OwnerID = $Owner.ObjectID -join ";"
                if ($owner.UserPrincipalName -eq $Null) {
                    $Username = $Owner.DisplayName + " **<This is an Application>**"
                }
                if ($Owner.DisplayName -eq $null) {
                    $Username = "<<No Owner>>"
                }

                $Log = New-Object System.Object
    
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ApplicationName" -Value $AppName
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ApplicationID" -Value $ApplID
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Secret Start Date" -Value $StartDate
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Secret End Date" -value $EndDate
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Certificate Start Date" -Value $Null
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Certificate End Date" -value $Null
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Owner" -Value $Username
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Owner_ObjectID" -value $OwnerID

                $Logs += $Log
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($c in $cert) {
        $CStartDate = $c.StartDate
        $CEndDate = $c.EndDate
        $COperation = $CEndDate - $now
        $CODays = $COperation.Days

        if ($AlreadyExpired -eq "No") {
            if ($CODays -le $Days -and $CODays -ge 0) {

                $Owner = Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $app.ObjectId
                $Username = $Owner.UserPrincipalName -join ";"
                $OwnerID = $Owner.ObjectID -join ";"
                if ($owner.UserPrincipalName -eq $Null) {
                    $Username = $Owner.DisplayName + " **<This is an Application>**"
                }
                if ($Owner.DisplayName -eq $null) {
                    $Username = "<<No Owner>>"
                }

                $Log = New-Object System.Object

                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ApplicationName" -Value $AppName
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ApplicationID" -Value $ApplID
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Certificate Start Date" -Value $CStartDate
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Certificate End Date" -value $CEndDate
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Owner" -Value $Username
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Owner_ObjectID" -value $OwnerID

                $Logs += $Log
            }
        }
        elseif ($AlreadyExpired -eq "Yes") {
            if ($CODays -le $Days) {

                $Owner = Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $app.ObjectId
                $Username = $Owner.UserPrincipalName -join ";"
                $OwnerID = $Owner.ObjectID -join ";"
                if ($owner.UserPrincipalName -eq $Null) {
                    $Username = $Owner.DisplayName + " **<This is an Application>**"
                }
                if ($Owner.DisplayName -eq $null) {
                    $Username = "<<No Owner>>"
                }

                $Log = New-Object System.Object

                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ApplicationName" -Value $AppName
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ApplicationID" -Value $ApplID
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Certificate Start Date" -Value $CStartDate
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Certificate End Date" -value $CEndDate
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Owner" -Value $Username
                $Log | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Owner_ObjectID" -value $OwnerID

                $Logs += $Log
            }
        }
    }
}

$p = Write-Output $Logs | Format-Table -Property "ApplicationName","Secret End Date","Certificate End Date","Owner" | Out-String

Write-host $p

#Write-host "Add the Path you'd like us to export the CSV file to, in the format of <C:\Users\<USER>\Desktop\Users.csv>" -ForegroundColor Green
#$Path = Read-Host
#$Logs | Export-CSV $Path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

Install-Module -Name PSSendGrid
Import-Module -Name PSSendGrid
$Parameters = @{
    FromAddress     = "kk****@abc.com"
    ToAddress       = "k********i@gmail.com", "kkucharkanti@gmail.com", "kkiran@ariqt.com"
    Subject         = "List of Expiring/Expired App registration keys/secrets Report - Ariqt & Ariqt-Dev/Test"
    Body            = "Below is list of Expiring/Expired App registration keys/secrets in 7 days $p"
    Token           = "SG.m1z9e*******************324w9hlTMb779xEvqIUjv0"
    #FromName        = "Barbara"
    #ToName          = "Barbara"
}
Send-PSSendGridMail @Parameters
```

Please help me what I am missing.

Comment: In which way you are trying to authenticate to your azure resources from the automation account (using managed identity, RunAsAccounts) as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-security-overview)

Comment: I am trying to authenticate with RunAsAccount

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect permissions. The ones you have are for PIM (Privileged Identity Management). To read data about App Regs you need one of these e.g.

[image]

Comment: I will try and let you know.

Comment: Still I am getting same error after giving the mentioned permissions. Below is the error
```
Get-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing GetApplications Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. RequestId: * DateTimeStamp: Tue, 01 Mar HttpStatusCode: Forbidden HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden HttpResponseStatus:At line:12 char:17 + $Applications = Get-AzureADApplication -all $true~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADApplication], ApiException+FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException